# Why does NoSuchMethodError get thrown when FinishAfterTransition is called?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, xamarin, android-appcompat

I'm creating Android application using Xamarin, AppCompat v4 and v7 packages (Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.23.0.1.3). I  need to reverse scene transition animation when I finish with the second activity pressing back button. I found a solution [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html). So, I'm using `FinishAfterTransition` method in overriden `OnBackPressed` in a class derived from `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class BaseToolbarActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        FinishAfterTransition();
    }
}
```

When I press the back button in an activity subclassed from `BaseToolbarActivity` I get the following error.

```
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557): Process: GetTruck.ClientApp, PID: 9557
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='finishAfterTransition' signature='()V' in class Landroid/app/Activity;
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at md5b2985d08cc2bafff83c57ef84572ed3f.CreateOrderActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at md5b2985d08cc2bafff83c57ef84572ed3f.CreateOrderActivity.onCreate(CreateOrderActivity.java:28)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
10-20 12:41:13.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 9557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

No matter in what order I call methods inside `OnBackPressed` my app crashes anyway. I also tried to rebuild the project, call `FinishAfterTransition` in other methods, all the same. Googling tells me nothing. It seems like I'm the only person on Earth who has come across this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code of FinishAfterTransition?

Comment: Umm, it's actually Activity method. Here's what I see in metadata of the dll:    `[Register("finishAfterTransition", "()V", "GetFinishAfterTransitionHandler")]
        public virtual void FinishAfterTransition();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FinishAfterTransition is actually an Activity (not AppCompatActivity) method that is only in API 21 and above (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAfterTransition()) therefore if you run the app in anything less than API 21, you'll run into that error because it doesn't exist.

Unfortunately because it is not part of the AppCompatActivity, you'll have to find another solution to achieve the result you want (or only call it on API >= 21).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, your answer leaves me with a new problem, but it is absolutely correct )